# Outlook 2016 has stopped working with Gmail IMAP

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, gmail-imap

I currently use Outlook 2016 as my mail client on my PC to access a couple GMAIL accounts via IMAP.  It has been working great for a couple years.  Just last week it stopped working.  Outlook started prompting me for the password for the Gmail account and will not connect anymore.  I can still access the email on my phone and via a web browser.  I attempted the follow so far with no sucess:

- repair the account in Outlook
- remove and re-add the account in outlook
- turn off less secure apps in Gmail Add 2 factor authentication in Gmail and an app password.

Each Time Outlook pops up a window asking me to sing into my account, I click Next.  Then it prompts for the password.  I enter the password and click Next.  I think get this window and click allow:

[image]

After I click allow I get this message:

[image]

How do I get this to work again?

Answer (score 0):

What specific operations did you do before this problem occurred?

Please try going to Outlook, click File > Office Account > Account Privacy > Manage Settings.

Check the box of "Enable optional connected experiences" > OK

If the issue continues, please change your Incoming mail Server to imap.googlemail.com and Outgoing mail Server to smtp.googlemail.com.

Hope this can be helpful.

Comment: I don't remember changing anything.  This was working just fine.  Looking at Windows update history, I took several updates on 9/12, but this problem did not start then.  I made the change in Outlook you suggested and no change - still cannot connect.  If I change from imap.gmail.com [Which Google lists to use] and try the one you listed, I get an error that the account and password do not match.  However, I can use them to log in to gmail via Chrome.